# Looking for something like Lucene for keyword indexing for use in a tree

Tags: search, tree, lucene, full-text-search

I've been looking to find an open source project (like Apache Lucene) to perform the following functions on a list of indexed objects (with properties like a text title & a list of associated keywords):

1. Perform searches on both the keywords & full text of the title
2. Create a ranked tree of keywords (based on the number of occurrences of the keyword). For example the top 10 key words over ALL objects are shown on the top level, then selecting a keyword you see a list of the top keywords associated with that keyword etc etc.

My idea is to use [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) which provides a great way to do full text and keyword search, but I'm not 100% sure how this would translate into created a ranked keyword tree.  Any other products that I may be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ranked keyword problem would probably be elegantly resolved by faceting . Say you have `foo` present in 10 documents on the `keyword` field, and `bar` present on 5 documents on the same field. Then faceting on the `keyword` field would give you 10 for foo and 5 for bar.

You can find a pretty well documented example here : http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/facet/org/apache/lucene/facet/doc-files/userguide.html